# Home Theater HDMI Splitting

Tags: home-theater

What is the best way to repeat a screen (HDMI) on two different devices without losing signal strength?

*Ex Projector screen and TV, one receiver, one input, without losing picture quality.*

I have a receiver that has one output, but I have two different devices that I want to use at any given time. Both are use 50ft HDMI cables that I manually unplug and plug depending on the screen I want to watch something on (movie vs news... sounds insane I know)

I see there are HDMI splitters out there but wasn't sure if that is the most optimal route or if there is a better option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 50ft cable is already sub-optimal ... just get an hdmi ab switch

Comment: what is the best way to transfer a signal 50FT?

Comment: also, AB Switch, I'm still having to pry my self from the couch to tap a button instead of swiping out HDMI cord. Any way to split and auto detect? or automate via Harmony Hub?

Comment: looking at your picture with the Illinois baseball shirt, i am guessing that you have walmart near you. ... they sell hdmi Y cable ... try it, and return it, if it does not work

Answer (score 2):

An HDMI splitter will work, though from the ones I've looked at, they have to send the exact same signal to both. So if one device is at 720p and the other 1080p, both will be forced down to 720p (HDMI is a two-way protocol, so I assume the splitter has a chip to negotiate this sort of thing). If only one output is on, it should work normally.

A simpler option for you, if you aren't planning on using both screens simultaneously, might be an HDMI switch, which just switches which output receives the input. Make sure to get one that's bi-directional, as the common use case for these would be switching the input, not the output. There are switches that have IR remotes which would work with your Harmony Hub.